# Bootstrap grid rearranging on smaller resolution

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, grid

I have a sample bootstrap grid as given in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mpsbhat/24cggL32/1).

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3">left</div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">Center</div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3">Right </div>
</div>
```

which draws the grid as [image]

When opening it in smaller resolution devices, it gives something like (if there is no `col-xs-*` class

[image]

But how can i manage to rearrange the grid like shown below in smaller resolution screens?
[image]

Comment: I don't know, would you like it, because it's no semantic solution: [jsfiddle-example](https://jsfiddle.net/Igor_Ivancha/24cggL32/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this, but it would require you to change the source order.

```css
.col{
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col col-md-push-3 col-md-6 col-xs-12">Center</div>
  <div class="col col-md-pull-6 col-md-3 col-xs-6">left</div>
  <div class="col col-md-3 col-xs-6">Right </div>
</div>
```